# laravel 5.2 authentication with username

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to authenticate user with username, not with email.

I tried to add protected field $username to authenticate users class,but didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: could you show code that you've tried.

Comment: just added $protected username = 'username'; to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController,nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you use Laravel default Authedication then you have to change your login form like Email filed to Name field this

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
@if ($errors->has('name'))
     <span class="help-block">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
     </span>
@endif
</div>
</div>
```

and go **AuthenticatesUsers** Controller change your function like

```
 public function loginUsername()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'name';
    }
```

Comment: I am not using default Authentication. I fixed it. added protected $username = 'username' to AuthController and that's it.